# Powers of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that $U$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[-1,1]$, and let $r$ be a non-negative integer. Find the distribution of $U^r$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed and look at the distribution function $F(u)=P(U^r\leq u)$, $u\in\mathbb{R}$.